# Dropbox Evernote integration

Tags: dropbox, evernote, integration, simplenote

Is there anyway I can ensure a sync between a folder full of text files and my Evernote/Eimplenote?

Update: I learnt that Evernote can "watch" any folder and import all the files inside. But it embeds the text files instead of importing them as notes.

Is there anyway to stop this? To force import as notes, and not as embedded items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplenote recently added [Dropbox syncing](http://simplenote.squarespace.com/news/2011/2/3/new-premium-features-dropbox-syncing-and-lists.html) as a premium feature:

> Dropbox is a great way to sync files. When you link your Dropbox account to your Simplenote account, all your notes in Simplenote will appear as text files in the Dropbox directory of your choice. Thereafter, your notes and files stay synchronized as you make changes. Syncing happens in both directions.

In my experience so far, the feature has not worked completely. The changes I make to the text files in my Dropbox folder do not get pushed to Simplenote's cloud. But I am hopeful that this will be [fixed soon](http://twitter.com/#!/simplenoteapp/status/33355446333095936).

[Notational Velocity](http://notational.net), a 3rd-party text editor that syncs with Simplenote, also supports storing its notes as text files, which you can [put onto Dropbox](https://github.com/scrod/nv/wiki/synchronizing-with-dropbox). But this solution is far from optimal since this ties the Dropbox syncing entirely to the single computer that you use NV on.

I realize this answer only addresses one part of the your question--the Simplenote side--and entirely ignores the Evernote side:)

Comment: I do the same thing for now. Use resophnotes, save files as text in the dropbox and use simplenote instead of Evernote.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [cloudHQ](http://cloudHQ.net/evernote). The service provides real-time and continuous synchronization of all Evernote notes with Dropbox.

Answer (score -2):

Our product, [CloudWork](http://cloudwork.com), is another tool that provides data integration between business apps.

You can synchronize Evernote and Dropbox by activating the stream that automatically uploads your Evernote attachments to Dropbox files.

That is the link to this specific [Evernote - Dropbox integration](https://cloudwork.com/integration/evernote-dropbox-backup-evernote-attachments-to-dropbox).

Comment: Please review the self promotion guidelines in our [faq#promotion]